# pyglet only play sound from same directory

Tags: python, audio, pyglet

So i have this piece of code which will play a sound but it only works if it is in the same directory

```
# Doesnt work
current_directory = os.getcwd()
path = os.path.join(current_directory + "\sounds\\monster_roar.wav")
music = pyglet.resource.media(path)

# does work
music = ("monster_roar.wav")
#music.play()
```

**pyglet.resource.ResourceNotFoundException: Resource "C:\Users\Joshua Nixon\Documents\college_work\extended_project\game\new\sounds\monster_roar.wav" was not found on the path.  Ensure that the filename has the correct captialisation.**

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using an absolute path instead of a relative path in cases like this. However, your error can likely be fixed with the following:

Instead of using 
`music = pyglet.resource.media(path)`

... try using `music = pyglet.media.load(path)`.

Comment: i love you, works. Could you explain the difference between relative and absolute path? Havent heard those terms

Comment: When you use a relative path like `\sounds\monster_roar.wav`, whatever function you are using has to calculate the full path at some point. This can be error prone, especially when running your program on different platforms.

An absolute path would be something like `C:\Users\Bob\Game\sounds\monster_roar.wav`. You wouldn't write this out as a string though, you would calculate it using os.path.abspath("sounds\monster_roar.wav"), which would yield different results on different platforms.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it too much for your case, but using an absolute path basically allows you to avoid having to join different paths (i.e. reduces the chance of an error).